# why test is failed bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

why test is failed, I tried with the several times, help to solve the below error

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators"
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA3NTEwOTMxMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjMyODgxMzE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDc1MGUyNzItNWRkOC00MjM1LWJjNjMtZTZlYWIxMGRmYzVlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzU3MDEyNjk@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTExMDk1MDE4NzVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDM4NDM0ODAx._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
         </div>
          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Error:

elf = <test_webpage.TestWebpage object at 0x7fc4e5c08a58>

```
def test_img(self):

    assert self._index.find('div',{'class':'carousel slide'})

    assert self._index.find('div',{'class':'item active'})

    site = self._index.find('div',{'class':'carousel slide'})

    a=0

    for img in site.find_all('img'):

        a=a+1
```

> ```
>   assert a==3
> ```

E       assert 0 == 3

test/test_webpage.py:21: AssertionError

Comment: You are using python instead of javascript for carousel.

Comment: I'm not using it, its predefined

Comment: ok, so you are facing problem in python or in bootstrap only. in bootstrap <ol> is not closed after indicators and (;) semicolon is wrong after the width="100%" in image.

Answer (score 0):

### Have a look at it. if it is working fine for you or not and let me know.

> Changes in:
>
> - In bootstrap  is not closed after indicators.
> - (;) semicolon is wrong after the width="100%" in image semicolon is not used.
> - .carousel-item is missing in carousel items.
> - For next carousel-control-next a class and for previous item .carousel-control-prev classes are their in bootstrap 4.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active active">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA3NTEwOTMxMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjMyODgxMzE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDc1MGUyNzItNWRkOC00MjM1LWJjNjMtZTZlYWIxMGRmYzVlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzU3MDEyNjk@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTExMDk1MDE4NzVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDM4NDM0ODAx._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
          
          
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon">
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon">
       <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </span>
  </a>
```

Comment: i have checked , for me it is working fine, for both online and offline. can you share any online link of your code so that i can check why your bootstrap is not working.

Comment: test/test_webpage.py::TestWebpage::test_img

  /projects/challenge/test/test_webpage.py:16: PytestAssertRewriteWarning: asserting the value None, please use "assert is None"

    assert self._index.find('div',{'class':'item active'})

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html

======================== 1 failed, 1 warnings in 0.18s =========================

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
***<ol class="carousel-indicators">***
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA3NTEwOTMxMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjMyODgxMzE@._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDc1MGUyNzItNWRkOC00MjM1LWJjNjMtZTZlYWIxMGRmYzVlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzU3MDEyNjk@._V1_SX1777_CR0,0,1777,999_AL_.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTExMDk1MDE4NzVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDM4NDM0ODAx._V1_SX1500_CR0,0,1500,999_AL_.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
     </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

use This code to solve this issue. *** line is showing ">" is missing here.